# Deploy redis stack server as sentinel with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, redis

I need to deploy redis-sentinel with redis-stack modules (redis-search and redis-json) by using docker compose but I can't find any reference. Can someone refer me to a docker compose example or explain how can I deploy it with docker?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have much experience with docker, but want a relatively "easy" way to setup with compose, you could take a look at Bitnami images.

For Redis Sentinel: [bitnami/redis-sentinel](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/redis-sentinel/).